# Visited and unvisited Google search results have identical styles in Safari 12.1

Tags: macos, safari

In Safari 12.1.1 for macOS (or perhaps since version 12.0), I've lost the ability to see which of Google's results I've already clicked on. The links corresponding to visited sites aren't colored differently from unvisited ones.

[image: safari makes no style-disctinction between visited and unvisited links on Google's search results page]

I have clicked on several links in the search results above, but as you can see, I am unable to determine which ones I've visited.

The distinction is visible in Chrome 74.0 as well as in Firefox 67.0.

What am I missing?

**Update**

This is observed by others as well, judging by Google suggesting the string "google safari visited links not changing color 2019" when typing the first few words, and by the posts on discussions.apple.com.

`maP1E bluE`'s solution works. If your "Show Develop menu in menu bar" is already checked, but your Develop menu's entries are disabled, including those under "Experimental Features", try to uncheck then check "Show Develop menu in menu bar" and/or to open a "New Private Window", from where you may be able to uncheck then check the "Swap Processes on Cross Site Navigation" entry.

**Update 2**

The solution doesn't last. This is simply a bug in Safari 12.1.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? The text “You visited this page on [date]” or the purple color visited links will get?

Comment: @grooveplex Visited links are not styled in purple. I added an image to illustrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Safari 12, possibly introduced only in Safari 12.1. It has not been fixed until Safari 12.1.2.

The problem is fixed in Safari 13.0. Visited links can again be identified by a distinct style.

*But* Safari 13.0 has another problem.

If you visit https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring
and search for the string `prima`, the four locations will be found using Chrome.  With Safari 13.0 only the first one is found; the remaining three instances are not.

**Update**

This second problem is solved in Safari 13.1.

Answer (score 1):

On Safari Menu Bar, select Preferences > Advanced > Show Develop menu in Menu Bar, then Develop > Experimental Features, unselect Swap Processes on Cross-Site Navigation.